# MongoDB get unique document which need to be compared with other documents in the same collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below is my sample documents structure in the test collection.

problem description:

I have to get the `name` field from this document based on the below condition.

I will pass the `role` field as query criteria. It should fetch the `name` values which is not related to `role` in the document.

please consider below documents.If my query criteria is role `r1` then the find query should return the names as:

`{"name":"S"},{"name":"G"}, {"name":"H"}`

because `r1` is not assigned to this names in any of the documents in the collection.

The same rule is applicable for all roles like `r2`,`r3`...`r7`.
so basically we have to look up all the documents in the collection and need to fetch names which is not assigned to any groups.

```
/* 0 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("567286bda5543ad892916a49"),
        "name" : "A",
        "role" : "r1"
    }

    /* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("567286bda5543ad892916a4a"),
        "name" : "A",
        "role" : "r2"
    }

    /* 2 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("567286bda5543ad892916a4b"),
        "name" : "A",
        "role" : "r3"
    }

    /* 3 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("567286bda5543ad892916a4c"),
        "name" : "B",
        "role" : "r2"
    }

    /* 4 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("567286bda5543ad892916a4d"),
        "name" : "A",
        "role" : "r4"
    }

    /* 5 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("567286bda5543ad892916a4e"),
        "name" : "B",
        "role" : "r1"
    }

    /* 6 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5672a8b7a5543ad892916a4f"),
        "name" : "S",
        "role" : "r3"
    }

    /* 7 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5672a8b7a5543ad892916a50"),
        "name" : "G",
        "role" : "r6"
    }

    /* 8 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5672a8b7a5543ad892916a51"),
        "name" : "H",
        "role" : "r2"
    }
```

Expected output:

```
-- input is role `r1` then (Need to show the name if `r1` is not associate already) -- same description for all the roles

    {"name" : "S"},
    {"name" : "G"},
    {"name" : "H"}

    -- input is role 'r2' then

    {"name" : "S"},
    {"name" : "G"}

    -- input is role 'r3' then

    {"name" : "B"},
    {"name" : "G"},
    {"name" : "H"}

    -- input is role 'r4' then

    {"name" : "B"},
    {"name" : "S"},
    {"name" : "G"},
    {"name" : "H"}

    -- input is role 'r6' then

    {"name" : "A"},
    {"name" : "B"},
    {"name" : "S"},
    {"name" : "H"}
```

any help is much appreciated. how to achieve this.`aggregation` framework or normal find query? please advice.

Comment: Please let me know the way to get it  done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('roles').aggregate([
    {$group: {_id:"$name", "roles":{$addToSet:"$role"}}},
    {$project: {_id:1, "roles": 1, "isSubset": { $setIsSubset: [ ["r1"], "$roles" ] }}},
    {$match: {"isSubset": false}},
    {$group: {_id:"$isSubset", "name": {$push : "$_id"}}},
    {$project: {"_id": 0, "name": 1}},
    {$unwind: "$name"}
])
```

1. Group by name, and push roles into an array.
2. Create the "isSubset" field that indicates if your "role" is a        subset from `roles` array".
3. Search only those whose "isSubset" field is false
4. Group by "isSubset"
5. Show only "name" field.
6. Unwind "name"

Comment: @Hecnanae : You are rocking. you made my day. Working greate. thanks alot. 

Is there any performace hit will rise if we go with this aggregation?

Comment: I don't know. It should be testing performance. 
I recommend this [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way to get this result than what has been accepted as the answer and I think the performance would be better. Just check it out:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
{ 
                  $group: { _id: null,             
                      rightrole: { $addToSet:  { $cond : {if: { $ne: [ "$role", "r1" ] }, then: "$name", else: null }} }, 
                      wrongrole: { $addToSet:  { $cond : {if: { $eq: [ "$role", "r1" ] }, then: "$name", else: null } } } } 
                          }, 
          {   "$project": {"_id": 0,         
                         "name": { "$setDifference": [ "$rightrole", "$wrongrole" ] } }
},              {$unwind: "$name"}
]);
```

1. Find the list of names that are not in the current role and add it
   to an array.
2. Find the list of names that are in the current role
   and add it to an array.
3. Find the difference between the 2 arrays
   using the $setDifference operator.
4. Unwind name